# Visual studio - .wxs documents auto-indent differently than .cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, auto-indent

I'm doing some C# programming and have lately been using .wxs files for my project.
When editing these documents in visual studio, they auto-indent differently than .cs files.

For new line, editor automatically indents with tabs instead of blank spaces. This goes through the coding guidelines that I'm using, and also the entire file is indented with blank spaces already.

[Old text above, new text below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgHpU.png)

Been trying to change my intentation settings but cannot seem to find how to change for a specific file type.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Do you use an `.editorconfig` file?

Comment: Yes apparently. Didn't know I had one. Found what I was looking for there!
Added wxs to it and voila, everyting is fine. Thank you!